# Deleting an attachment, with known naming convention, in an Outlook email

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

In Microsoft Outlook 365 (V1912), I am trying to remove a single attachment from a set of files that have been attached from a VBA script that attaches all the .PDF files in a specified directory.

When I try to run my script, I am presented with an error that I know is due to not specifying/using the right syntax.

> Invalid procedure call or argument

I researched and tried all sorts of fixes, but the information I can find is either for Excel or suggestions on how to strip all attachments from an email.

```
Dim JobLocation As String

ClientDirectory = "C:\ClientDirectory\" & JobLocation & "\Files\"
RequiredPDFs = Dir(ClientDirectory & "*.pdf")
Do While Len(RequiredPDFs) > 0
    .Attachments.Add ClientDirectory & RequiredPDFs
    RequiredPDFs = Dir
Loop

For i = 0 To (.Attachments.Count - 1)
    If InStr(1, .Attachments, JobLocation & "_SM ") Then
        .Attachments.Remove 1
    End If
Next i
```

The first half of the code loops through all files in the directory and attaches them.

There is one file that has the naming convention JobLocation_SM 1234 that I want  to either not attach or delete after attaching all other files, if the file exists in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim att

For Each att in .Attachments
    If InStr(1, att.FileName, JobLocation & "_SM ") > 0 Then
        att.Delete
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Yep ! This worked perfectly (once I removed the i from Next i)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are hardcoding index 1 instead of i when calling `Attachments.Remove`.

Secondly, all collections in Outlook are 1 based, not 0.

Thirdly, if there are multiple matches, the loop won't work since you are modifying (by deleting) the collection you are looping over. Use a down loop:

```
For i = .Attachments.Count to 1 step -1
```

Fourthly, why are you deleting attachments after adding them? Wouldn't it be easier to avoid adding them in the first place?

Fifthly, you are not accessing the Attachment object in your loop;

```
For i = .Attachments.Count to 1 step -1
   set attach = .Attachments.Item(i)
   If InStr(1, attach.FileName, JobLocation & "_SM ") Then
     attach.Delete
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: OP asks for not attaching (`either not attach or delete`), so provide that solution! But the trap on`For Each` with delete is not well known and a good hint too.